# How to reduce Phytate in pea protein isolate?

Tags: nutrient-composition

I have found that pea protein isolate has high phytate content that inhibits mineral absorption. Some articles from a company that sells it quote a low number but other research does not confirm it. I wanted to use pea protein isolate in a shake.

Now what kind of cooking treatment will be required to reduce the phytate content of pea protein before using it in a shake?

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually do it by cooking - it's part of the peas. You should use a different protein.